# NVIDIA Quadro 4000 installation on a 4,1 Mac Pro

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I bought a Quadro 4000 but have not received it. The following instruction was by the Amazon seller:
"Must use driver for MAC downloaded from Nvidia directly. DO NOT LET APPLE SOFTWARE UPDATE INSTALL DRIVER! Use only Nvidia direct driver. Failure to use latest Nvidia driver will delay returns and buyer will incur shipping charges for both directions! Installation must be done in parallel with existing video card in MAC Pro. This requires power for second card (Q4000) and monitor connection to first card to facilitate driver installation."

My concern regards installation of the *correct* Nvidia Driver or Driver(s). Is it only a Cuda Driver and if so which one. I'm afraid that the wrong Driver may either not work or even cause harm to the card. The Nvidia website lists many versions and revisions of the Drivers. There are also overlapping compatibilities and years.

The card installed is the NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 1024 MB and it works fine but I'm trying to upgrade my 4,1 speed. So far I've maxed out the memory and added a 2TB SSD.

Comment: You cannot harm a GPU by using the incorrect drivers.  The drivers offered by Nvidia are NOT simply CUDA drivers.  [This](http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html) website has direct downloads to the Nvidia drivers for each version of macOS.  **Honestly. it's extremely unlikely that upgrading the drivers will bring any significant performance increase.**

Comment: @Ramhound - those NVidia web drivers for Mac Pros are really, really twitchy & you have got to get the right drivers for the right OS. Trouble is, you can't see the screen before login, so you can get locked out if you get it wrong on a non-Mac-flashed card. It doesn't hurt the card, just the user ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I suspected Nvidia support wasn't cut and dry, I actually thought, there was zero support for Nvidia cards on macOS.  Which of course is there I stopped short of suggesting a specific driver.  I also made perhaps a bad assumption that the author was an experienced macOS user.  It was also easy enough to confirm that the CUDA drivers are indeed separate.

Comment: @Ramhound -  Indeed the CUDA drivers are separate - I don't know of any rules specifying which you need for CUDA though. Apple's drivers are fine for almost all situations except for Mac Pros, which are about the only Macs you can retrofit newer GPUs. Up to a point, AMD cards 'just work' until you hit generational differences on 10-year-old Pros that just cannot handle the very new cards. I think Apple kind of fell out with NVidia for a time [Macs through that period are AMD] so NVidia stepped up to fill a gap, until Mojave stopped them. All the Pros here have AMD, to avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

What OS is on the Mac?

The seller's "advice" makes it pretty certain that they're not selling you a proper Mac-flashed card but a generic "PC" one. They seem to be pre-empting you discovering their failure & making it all your fault, rather than theirs.

They're also giving very bad advice with "install the latest drivers". That is certainly not the case. They also seem to have absolutely no idea that macOS will not "update drivers" through Software Update. Drivers are included in the OS version itself, they are not a separate entity - in all but this very small window in which the NVidia web drivers are available for certain cards.
NVidia "web drivers" are very specific to exactly which OS you have installed & there are no web drivers at all for Mojave or later. The regular Apple drivers kind of work for NVidia cards outside this window, but it's a gamble. The web driver itself has a switchable pref, so you can test & reboot, swap back & re-test to see which works best, Apple or NVidia.

The very best source of information on exactly which drivers you need for which macOS has always been MacVidCards [who incidentally don't sell a Quadro 4000, only the 5000 - idk how significant that might be] - http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html

If you are going to attempt this, make sure you don't have filevault enabled, or any type of firmware lock, or you won't be able to get in once you removed your GT120. You will also not be able to use any pre-boot environment, such as holding Opt to choose a boot volume or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  to get to recovery. Your screen will be black until you get to login.
Those pre-boot options all need a Mac-flashed card. You would have to put your GT120 back in to be able to do that, in case of emergency.

Note: You can find your exact OS build from About This Mac > System report… > Software

[image]